# prove $d(\vec{x},\vec{y})=d(\vec{y},\vec{x})$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Prove $d(\vec{x},\vec{y})=d(\vec{y},\vec{x})$

---

My attempt:

$$d(\vec{x},\vec{y})=||\vec{y}-\vec{x}||$$
$$=\sqrt{(y_1-x_1)^2+...(y_n-x_n)^2}$$
Squarring then taking the square root gives us
$$=|(y_1-x_1)|+...|(y_n-x_n)|= |(x_1-y_1)|+...|(x_n-y_n)|$$
Now,
$$\sqrt{(|(x_1-y_1)|)^2+...(|(x_n-y_n)|)^2}= \sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+...(x_n-y_n)^2}$$
$$=||\vec{x}-\vec{y}||=d(\vec{y},\vec{x})$$

---

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Or just use directly the fact that $(a-b)^2 = (b-a)^2$ without squaring and retaking a square root.

Comment: Also, $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\neq a+b$